# Why does \color{blue} differ from \color{Blue}?

Tags: color

```
    \documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \begin{document}
    {\color{Blue}\bf Blue} versus {\color{blue}\bf blue}.
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Why does one of them differ from the other one?

---

**EDIT 1**

1. I still wonder why the color is distinguished by capitalization :-)
2. Why did the package author choose `dvipsnames` as the option name? I think this name potentially makes us obtain a wrong impression from it that is usually used to describe the driver? In fact both `pdflatex` and `latex` can use it, right?

Comment: Again: It is the consensus on this site that the latex tags should generally be avoided.

Comment: are *really* you a conforming implementation? If not, you probably shouldn't be using that name...

Comment: Because the programmers are neither typographers, nor printers. Both `Blue` vs. `blue` and `dvipsnames` are arbitrary (wrong) choices without any practical reason. However, this isn't TeX but color science... Nobody prints in RGB, and there is no such a thing as colors "more fit for human consumption". There is Pantone in printing, etc...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A natural color is defined by its wavelength. If you want to print it you
have to convert it into a color model which allows the mixing of base colors
into the needed color. Such color models are very different and a blue in 
model A is often different to a blue in model B.

"blue" is a `rgb` color and "Blue" is defined as a `cmyk` color and handled by a different driver for your output. If you want to be sure, that you use the same driver, then specify one:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}


\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

{\color{Blue}\bf Blue} versus {\color{blue}\bf blue}.

\end{document}
```

instead of [rgb] you can also use [cmyk]

[image]

Comment: thanks for informing the options `[rgb]` and `[cmyk]` that I always ignore.

Answer (score 26):

Because that's how the colours are defined `:)`

Colour names are case sensitive, and `red`, `green`, `blue` are the ‘standard’ `(1,0,0)`, `(0,1,0)`, `(0,0,1)` RGB colours respectively.

In section 4 of the `xcolor` manual (pg. 38 for v2.11) the list of other colour names is given; under the `dvipsnames` section you can see that there are many more colours defined with initial-uppercase names. Personally, I find those `Red`, `Blue`, and (especially) `Green` colours to be much more attractive as they are a little more muted.

Comment: @Will, thank you very much. The package author did it intentionally, the colors depend on the letter case? :D

Comment: @xport: Yes, color names are case-sensitive, just like most TeX names.  The lower-case ones are the "primary" screen colors (not defined by `xcolor`) while the capitalized ones are, as Will said, the ones more fit for human consumption.

Comment: @Matthew, but it looks so funny---Theoritically each color has a specific wavelength, so its name should be unique regardless of the capitalization I think :D

Comment: @xport: Yes, but while each color has a specific wavelength, each color does not have a specific name.

Comment: @Matthew, the current mapping has no inverse. :D Thank you. Closed.

Comment: @Will, your answer is good, but I prefer Herbert's explanation. That why I switch to his answer to be GREEN checked.